# Complex linq query with sub properties

Tags: linq, nested

Can't seem to find an answer to my question.
I'm using Google CSE, and in the result set, I wish to get all the items where "positiveVotes" is more than 5.

I can't seem to understand how to get all items where a sub-sub-sub property answers a criteria.
it's basically suppose to be something like this:

```
results.Items
            .Where(x => x.Pagemap.Where(a => a.Key == "discussion").Where(key == "positiveVotes" and value > 5)
```

but I really don't know how to write it.
Please help.

Comment: I think it would be easier to have the corresponding classes to this query.

Comment: This is for "discussion": System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]]]} , which his value is a List of key/value pair, which his value is another list of key/value pair, and one of the keys is "positivevotes"

Comment: Why was this downvoted?

Comment: I did not downvote,  but I think it is very hard to understand what you are trying to accomplish. From my point of view you have to extend the question with more data like the data structure you want to query. This is important to answer your question and nothing just for 'discussion'.

Comment: Ok. Let me try to explain. I need to query a complex structure: a list of type "Results" which contains properties. one of the properties is called "PageMap", Inside, there's a list of dictionary, which one of the keys is named "discussion". this "discussion" is a key, and its corresponding value is a list of key/value pairs. one of the keys is named "positiveVotes". I want to get all the items from the main list, which the "positiveVotes" value is more than 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit difficult to understand exactly what your data structure is without you providing the exact type of `results`, but this is my best guess of what you need:

```
results.Items
       .Where(x => x.Pagemap.ContainsKey("discussion")
           && x.PageMap["discussion"].Any(kvp => kvp.Key == "positiveVotes" && kvp.Value > 5))
```

Answer (score 0):

Could this solve your problem?

```
results.Items
    .Where(x => x.Key == "discussion")
    .Select(x => x.Value)
    .Cast<KeyValuePair<string, int>>()
    .Where(k => k.Key == "positiveVotes" && k.Value > 5);
```

Comment: Hi Core. Thank you for your answer: what you suggested does not compile. "Result does not contain a definition for key.." it's suppose to be something like:
"            var relevantSites = results.Items
                .Where(a => a.Pagemap.Where(b => b.Key == "discussion"))
                .Where(x => x.Where(y => y.Key == "positivevotes").value > 5)